# Pagination not working properly after adding in button for admin

Tags: php, pagination

I have pagination for a table to display data from the database in the table. This was working fine and I tried to add in a button which only admin's can see. If the user is not an admin they will not see this button. This feature works but once I did it, the pagination only shows one row of data compared to the maximum of 10 per page.

This is my code:

```
         public function dataview($query)
 {
     $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
     $stmt->execute();

     if($stmt->rowCount()>0) // display records if there are records to display
     {
            while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $poll_id = $row['poll_id'];
                $question = $row['question'];
               ?>
               <tr>
               <td><?php echo $row['poll_id']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['question']; ?></td>
               <td><a href="openPoll.php?poll_id=<?php echo $poll_id; ?>">Open Poll</a></td>
               <td><a href="openResults.php?poll_id=<?php echo $poll_id; ?>">Results</a></td>
               <?php
                     $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id");
                     $stmt->execute(array(':user_id'=>$_SESSION['user_session']));
                     $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                     if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                     $admin = $userRow['admin'];
                     if($admin == 1){
               ?>
               <td><a href="deletePoll.php?poll_id=<?php echo $poll_id; ?>">Delete Poll</a></td>
               <?php

               ?>

               </tr>

               <?php
                     }
                     }
            }
     }
     else
     {
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td>Nothing here...</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
     }
```

}

and this is the code on the html page which uses the pagination

```
    <table align="center" border="1" width="100%" height="100%" id="data">
            <?php 
            $query = "SELECT * FROM polls";       
            $records_per_page=10;
            $newquery = $paginate->paging($query,$records_per_page);
            $paginate->dataview($newquery);
            $paginate->paginglink($query,$records_per_page);  
            ?>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reusing variables like `$stmt` inside the loop that uses it. So do this:

```
 $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
 $stmt->execute();

 if($stmt->rowCount()>0) // display records if there are records to display
 {
        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $poll_id = $row['poll_id'];
            $question = $row['question'];
           ?>
           <tr>
           <td><?php echo $row['poll_id']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['question']; ?></td>
           <td><a href="openPoll.php?poll_id=<?php echo $poll_id; ?>">Open Poll</a></td>
           <td><a href="openResults.php?poll_id=<?php echo $poll_id; ?>">Results</a></td>
           <?php
                 $stmt2 = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id");
                 $stmt2->execute(array(':user_id'=>$_SESSION['user_session']));
                 $userRow=$stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                 if($stmt2->rowCount() > 0){
                 $admin = $userRow['admin'];
                 if($admin == 1){
           ?>
           <td><a href="deletePoll.php?poll_id=<?php echo $poll_id; ?>">Delete Poll</a></td>
           <?php

           ?>

           </tr>

           <?php
                 }
                 }
        }
 }
 else
 {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td>Nothing here...</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
 }
```

I have replace the `$stmt` inside the loop by `$stmt2`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem. I should have known this.